# How does the method "with_optimizer" work?

Tags: optimization, julia

I am trying to run the following Julia code:

```
using Pkg

Pkg.add("Ipopt")
Pkg.add("Clp")
Pkg.add("GLPK")
using JuMP, Ipopt, Clp, GLPK
model = Model(with_optimizer(GLPK.Optimizer))
optimize!(model)
```

the error I get is:
UndefVarError: `with_optimizer` not defined

How do i solve this? I installed and reinstalled JuMP quiet a few times

Answer (score 0):

You are likely reading an old example based on a pre-1.0 version of JuMP. The `with_optimizer` function was [deprecated in JuMP version 0.21 back in 2020](https://jump.dev/JuMP.jl/latest/release_notes/#%5BVersion-0.21.0%5D(https://github.com/jump-dev/JuMP.jl/releases/tag/v0.21.0)-(Feb-16,-2020)). Just pass the optimizer factory directly to the [`Model` constructor](https://jump.dev/JuMP.jl/latest/api/JuMP/#Model), like so:

```
using JuMP, GLPK
model = Model(GLPK.Optimizer)
optimize!(model)
```

You can also set the optimizer any time after constructing the `Model` (but before calling `optimize!`) with [`set_optimizer`](https://jump.dev/JuMP.jl/latest/api/JuMP/#JuMP.set_optimizer), like so:

```
using JuMP, GLPK
model = Model()
set_optimizer(model, GLPK.Optimizer)
optimize!(model)
```